# Symmetry of points on unit sphere determined by relation between triples of points

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetry

Suppose we have $n$ points on the 3D unit sphere,

$X = (\pmb{r}_{1}, \pmb{r}_{2}, ..., \pmb{r}_{n})$.

I am interested in knowing to what extent the rotational symmetry of $X$ is determined by the following constraint. Every ordered triple of points ($n^{3}$ of them in total) is related to at least one other triple of points by some rotation about the origin,

$(\pmb{r}_{j_{1}}, \pmb{r}_{j_{2}}, \pmb{r}_{j_{3}}) = (R\pmb{r}_{l_{1}}, R\pmb{r}_{l_{2}}, R\pmb{r}_{l_{3}})$,

where $R$ is a rotation (not the identity) depending on $j_{1}, j_{2}, j_{3}$. The triple $l_{1}, l_{2}, l_{3}$ must be distinct from $j_{1}, j_{2}, j_{3}$, but perhaps only in order.

Clarification:

If the collection of points has rotational symmetry,

$\pmb{r}_{\sigma(j)} = R \pmb{r}_{j}$,

where $R$ is the same for all $j$ and $\sigma$ is a permutation, then the constraint is obviously satisfied. It is thus not hard to find a collection of points satisfying the constraint. What I'm interested in is what one can conclude in the opposite direction: what can one say about the symmetry of the collection of points if the constraint is satisfied (perhaps nothing)?

At one extreme, if the triple is replaced by an $n$-tuple, the collection of points must have some rotational symmetry. One of the constraints is

$(\pmb{r}_{1}, \pmb{r}_{2}, \dots, \pmb{r}_{n}) = (R \pmb{r}_{\sigma(1)}, R \pmb{r}_{\sigma(2)}, \dots R \pmb{r}_{\sigma(n)})$,

which implies

$\pmb{r}_{j} = R \pmb{r}_{\sigma(j)}$.

At the other extreme, where the triple is replaced by a single point, the constraint is obviously satisfied by any collection of points on the sphere. (Every point on the sphere is related to every other point by some rotation about the origin.)

What can one say between these two extremes?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: And presumably $(l_1, l_2, l_3)$ is also allowed to depend on $(j_1, j_2, j_3)$?

Comment: That's right. For every $j_{1}, j_{2}, j_{3}$ there is some $l_{1}, l_{2}, l_{3}$ such that the equation is satisfied for some rotation.

Comment: Do you have an example of such a tuple with not all coördinates equal?  (Also, you haven't specified the dimension; are we working in the unit sphere in the same $\mathbb R^n$ as the number of points, or could the dimension vary?)

Comment: I'm only interested in 3D and $n > 3$. A  rotationally-symmetric polyhedron with vertices on the unit sphere obviously satisfies the constraint, but I would like to know what can be said in the opposite direction.

Comment: Take two points $r_1$ and $r_2$ on the sphere and in the $(x, y)$-plane.  Reflect $r_2$ about the diametre (of the circle in the $(x, y)$-plane) through $r_1$ to get $r_3$.  Reflect $r_1$, $r_2$, and $r_3$ about the diametre perpendicular to the one throguh $r_1$ to get $r_4$, $r_5$, and $r_6$.  I think that this tuple satisfies your condition.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The hexagon corresponding to the six points you described has two-fold rotational symmetry about an axis passing through $r_{1}$. I would like to know whether satisfying the constraint always implies some sort of rotational (perhaps also reflection) symmetry of the points.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Sorry, I thought you meant full rotational symmetry.  Of course I now see that any rotational symmetry is good enough.

Comment: Is "at least one other triple" three different indices or at least one different index?

Comment: Thanks for your question. The triple $j_{1}, j_{2}, j_{3}$ might differ from $l_{1}, l_{2}, l_{3}$ only in order. The ordered triples are distinct. I've updated the question to make this point clearer.

Comment: In this case, could you have an equilateral triangle at the north pole and one at the equator, in which case $X$ has no rotational symmetry but each triangle is related to itself in different order?

Comment: With two equilateral triangles, each triangle obviously rotates onto itself. So two of the 6! triples of points satisfy the constraint. How about triples composed of two corners of one triangle and one corner of the other?